# Integrate $\frac{dx}{x^{2n}+1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can one calculate

$$
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{2n} + 1}, \;n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

without using complex plane and Residue theorem?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457/515527

Answer (score 1):

With $x=\tan^{1/n} t$ and some well-known properties of the Gamma function, you can prove the answer is $2/\operatorname{sinc}\frac{\pi}{2n}$. The case $n=1$ is an easy sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the integral 
$$F(a,b,c)=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^a}{(t^b+1)^c}\mathrm dt$$
Set $x^{1/b}=t$:
$$F(a,b,c)=\frac1b\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{
\frac{a+1}b}}{(x+1)^c}\mathrm dx$$
Then $u=\frac1{x+1}$ gives 
$$\begin{align}
F(a,b,c)&=\frac1b\int_0^1 \left[\frac{1-u}{u}\right]^{
\frac{a+1}b}u^c\frac{\mathrm du}{u^2}\\
&=\frac1b\int_0^1u^{c-2-\frac{a+1}{b}}(1-u)^{\frac{a+1}b}\mathrm du
\end{align}$$
Then recall the definition of the Beta function:
$$\mathrm{B}(x,y)=\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\mathrm dt=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
Where $\Gamma(s)$ is the gamma function. So of course we have 
$$F(a,b,c)=\frac1b\mathrm{B}\left(c-1-\frac{a+1}b,1+\frac{a+1}b\right)$$
We then have your integral as 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{t^{2n}+1}=F(0,2n,1)$$